# How to integrate 3 wpf application in one application?

Tags: wpf

Here am having 3 different WPFapplications and now my requirement is like i want to have only one WPF app which should be invoke the other apps pages when clicking the hyperlink..
Can anyone suggest how to do that...

I tried with one type of solution i.e. having the other three has class lib and invoke the corresponding pages using the created objects, but that is not working.
please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "that is not working"? any specific errors?

Comment: Not able to load the page ...am getting as null

Answer (score 1):

Building a Composite Application could be the way to go here. Check out these links:

[Patterns For Building Composite Applications With WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx)

[patterns & practices: Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

[Introduction to Composite WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37164/Introduction-to-Composite-WPF-CAL-Prism-Part-1)

In this pattern each application is called 'Module' and is created as a library that is loaded by a main 'Shell'. The sample in the codeproject link will give you a nice first look about it.